# A better way to say "to prove efficiency"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

In the conclusion part of my thesis,  I want to describe the efficiency of a proposed method X.

So can we say:

- X has been proved as a powerful method for...

OR:

- X proved its efficiency as a method for...

I believe there is a better way to compose the above sentence.

Comment: If it's your thesis, then you proved something, not X. X is your creation and it can't prove anything; it's at most a physical object, but more likely an abstract concept. And before you claim proof, remember that demonstration is a weaker but much more justifiable claim. And recall that _efficiency_ has many definitions.

Comment: @JohnLawler Actually, the method is a deep learning model. This model performs a task. Therefore I though that I can say "X proved its efficiency...".

Comment: This might be a good place for a passive: x was proven to be efficient or something like that. One assumes you're gonna give numbers and charts in any case.

Comment: Hi, are you asking about the verb (passive voice vs. active voice) or is this question more about synonyms for powerful efficiency?

Comment: If this is a thesis, and this is your conclusion, is it better to say: It has been shown that X is an efficient method... ?

Comment: _X has been **proven** to be a powerful method for... _

Comment: Powerful and Efficient are not synonyms.  'Efficient' doesn't stand alone very well,  does it make efficient use of time, money, materials, effort? etc?  They're both relative terms, and without a comparison are meaningless i.e. what are they more efficient or powerful than? Is it the *most* efficient or powerful method or just one of many?

Comment: @livresque Actually, I am asking about active vs. passive

Comment: @GArthurBrown I think it is the best choice :)

Comment: What do you mean by efficiency? The word generally has a precise meaning in a scientific or academic context (the efficiency of the internal combustion engine, the efficiency of the glycolytic pathway) but not in a general context. If it is not obvious that it has such a precise meaning in your thesis, avoid it and say exactly how Method X is better.